# innerHTML failing to inject text into markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I am learning about jQuerys `animate` and am building a small game where the user has to catch the box by trying to click on it and for every click the score increments by 1 point which is displayed dynamically on screen inside a `<P>` element.

The problem is that the score is not showing in `<p>`.

By debugging the application I can see that the score is infact being incremented so a flaw in incrementation is ruled out. The only other possibility I though that the reason was because `$(document).ready` was not being fired on each `click` but that is false because the score does infact increment. So my only solution that I can think of is that there is something going on behind the scenes with the way I have implemented `.innerHTML` but I cannot get my head around it.

I have tried using `value()` instead of `toString()` as I initially believed that getting the actual `value` of variable `points` would return its raw numeric value but that didnt do anything.

Here is the jQuery line I am having problems with:

```
var points = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    Animate();
    div.on('mousedown', function () {
        points += 1;
        $('#points').innerHTML += points.toString();
    });
});
```

And the HTML markup that it is referencing:

```
<body>
    <p id="points">Total points: </p>
    <div id="box"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Please note that the point score needs to be **added** into `<p>` **not** replacing the contents of `<p>` for example if the point is incremented `<p>` will show `Total Points: 1`

And here is my [JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6oquqtrr/2/) for a complete view of the problem

Comment: `$('#points')[0].innerHTML += points.toString();` or `$('#points').html(function(i,html){ return html + points.toString(); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/6oquqtrr/4/)

### HTML

```
<p id="points">Total points: <span id="total-points"></span></p>
<div id="box"></div>
```

### Remove this Javascript

```
$('#points').innerHTML += points.toString();
```

### Replace with this

```
$('#total-points').text(points);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var totPoints="Total points: "; // define a variable with this string value
    Animate();
    div.on('mousedown', function () {
        points += 1;
        $('#points').html( totPoints+ points.toString()); // concatenate and add the html
        alert("Points" + points.toString());// Wrote this to prove that    points score IS being incremented
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Insted of using innerHtml u can direcly use  `$('#points').html( "Total points: "+ +points.toString());`

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/surajAhirrao/6oquqtrr/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using $("#points").html(points); this will work.

using .innerHTML with jquery will give problems as jquery uses this in a different manner to pure js.